# Javascript SRC PHP file

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way of using Javascript to include an external PHP file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget.php?hash=2&b=NTdhZmI3"></script>
```

I'm new to this type of method and I'm not sure if I will run into complications using this type of include.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** The script works as intended, and the PHP file outputs as JS. I'm just looking to see if this is good practice or if there is a better alternative.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What would be more efficient?  No complications at all with what you show.

Comment: I'm just including a little script for tracking visitor information, throughout mt own sites. Just wanted to do it through a Javascript include. The PHP file headers are set and the script works very well, just wondering if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: Is widget.php has javascript code as output? If you just want to include php using `<script>`, exactly you can't.

Comment: If you need to generate Javascript dynamically, this is a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: if widget.php do act like `.js`, I think, you already do well.

Comment: I'm agreed with @Barmar, by the way, the only difference between use the usual (.js) and the dinamic (.php) is that with php you just make a simple output and put the server to work a bit more, the rest, just the same, there's no even bandwidth difference at all (apart VERY LITTLE php header variables).. don't give bad life..

Comment: would this raise an issue with caching the js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not have any specific method to include files. We must do it on server  side includes. I think you are using php in server side so include your file in php itself with include() or require().

But still there are three way in javascript in which you can do it.

1. **Script tag** (what you are doing) : Script tag import almost every file (text files), but the output must be js acceptable scripts or codes. You can include other formats also. Just put it on javascript variable and document.write it.
   Like you file will contain element like.

   var html='< div class="header"><img src="logo.png"> Some more header stuffs </div>';
   document.write(html);
2. **Ajax** : With ajax you can call any file too an manipulate its response as you want. But for file including sense it is not useful . It is better to load dynamic content. Take a scenario you want to include header file, and you did it with ajax now what will happen your body will load first and then it will display header (as ajax is asynchronous) which will look too bad.
3. **iFrames**  : iframes are easiest way to include files. But they are ugly and not supposed because of many issues like linking issue, broken html, manupulating data etc, caching issue.

Answer (score 1):

This works or you could use AJAX with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "widget.php",
    data: "hash=2&b=NTdhZmI3",
    success: function(response) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.innerHTML = response;
        document.getElementsByName[0].appendChild(script);
    },

    error: function (e) {
        //error callback code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: Just the same with more code, you request a php file, php file gets processed, php final output gets downloaded, the result is just the same..

Comment: I know its the same but if he wants to load it using AJAX then here is how

Comment: What would be the advantages of using jQuery here? If you don't list them, your answer is quite invalid. And no, you would just use `$.getScript`

Comment: This is a basically $.getScript and the advantage of using AJAX is that then most browsers wouldn't load the script with such a high priority (which is good because its just a tracking script)